# How to check if this weird vector field is conservative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I need to check if this vector field is conservative: ('$\mathrm{sgn}$' is the sign function)

$$F=(\dfrac{y\cdot\mathrm{sgn}(xy)}{1+|xy|},\dfrac{x\cdot\mathrm{sgn}(xy)}{1+|xy|})$$

Do I need to check separately for $x<=0,x=0,x>0$? but what about the absolute value? Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: just prove path independence

Comment: You can check it in $4$ cases that covers the absolute value too: i) $x,y > 0$ ii) $x,y <0$  iii) $x > 0, y<0$ iv) $x<0, y > 0$. If $x$ or $y$ is zero, then it's very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}\left(\frac y{1+xy}\;,\;\;\frac x{1+xy}\right)\,,&xy\ge0\\{}\\\left(-\frac y{1-xy}\;,\;\;-\frac x{1-xy}\right)\,,&xy<0\end{cases}$$

and now

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac x{1+xy}\right)=\frac{1+xy-xy}{(1+xy)^2}=\frac1{(1+xy)^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac y{1+xy}\right)$$

and by symmetry (observe both minus signs in the second row of the definition of $\;F$) , we get that $\;F\;$ is conservative wherever it is definee, i.e.: in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$

Comment: $xy<0$ implies that $x$ or $y$ has to be negative,Right ? They have to have opposite sign

Comment: @NPLS Yes, of course...why would we care about this? All that matters here is, as far as I understand the question, the sign of $\;xy\;$ . Each particular sub-case is not of our interest, imo.